# Best way to route after delay in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'm looking to trigger a route to another page in React (using React Router) after an animation is triggered. Off the top of my head, I know I can trigger the animation and Route after a `setTimeout` is complete, but something tells me that is not a good way to do it. Am I wrong about that, or is there a better way to cause a delay in routing to another page?

An example of what I'm thinking:

```
target.style.animation = 'example';
setTimeout(() => {
   //Route here
}, 2500);
```

Comment: What routing library are you using? And what kind of animation do you want to show? Some additional code to show the context would be helpful, as well.

Comment: @MatthewBrooks Hi sorry about that. React Router and just a simple CSS animation. I want to fade some text out after a button is clicked, then route to another page.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on a recent version of React, you can use the `useHistory` hook from `react-router` to programmatically navigate by calling `history.push("/my-next-route")` in your `setTimeout` callback. Check out the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) for an example.

If your animation is already working and all you need to do is add the actual navigation part, that should get you there. If you want to know the "right" way to do this, you'll need to post more code so we can see exactly what you're trying to accomplish. There are some libraries for handling animations in React, and some others that help combine that with routing, but I can't recommend that as a solution without more context.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Will look into the useHistory hook.